# "ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function sum(character varying) does not exist" rails error only on production with .sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

The error above is what I get when trying to use .sum on Heroku. I dont know what the problem is and have no way to test it because everything is working fine on development. The .sum code is:

```
CallLog.where(date: Date.today).sum(:duration).round(3)
```

The duration column is a decimal.

Comment: My first thought is are you running the same version of Rails in both environments?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your `duration` column is of type `varchar` in production.
Perhaps you defined it with wrong datatype in the beginning and then changed it in your migration file?

You can find the current type with:

`SELECT pg_typeof(duration) FROM call_logs LIMIT 1`

You will need to change the type with something like:

`alter table call_logs alter column duration type numeric(10,0) using duration::numeric`

This only works if the column contains data that can be casted to numeric. If not the `using` part will fail. Clean up the data in this case and then try to change it again.

Be sure to back up the DB before and select the right type (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html) for your case.

Note: I assumed that `duration` is a number (e.g. number of seconds)